# Email sent from my new server, being suspended by SMTP because "weird" hostname?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, hostname

I have some problems sending emails from my server: I've been **banned/suspended for abuse (IP blocked) by the SMTP server**. This **happens only on my new virtual server**.

Right to the question: is my new server misconfigured? How can I fix it, hoping that this would fix the suspension problem as well?

The story:

#### New server `Received` header

This is part of the headers of a message sent from a PHP script running on my private virtual server:

```
Received: from apogeo.hpsart.it (31-193-130-251.static.as29550.net
 [31.193.130.251])
```

The weird part is the `31-193-130-251.static.as29550.net` instead of the hostname. SMTP server/client interaction:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtps.pec.aruba.it ESMTP Postfix
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO apogeo.hpsart.it
[...]
SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 554 5.7.1 <31-193-130-251.static.as29550.net
[31.193.130.251]>: Client host rejected: IP address banned for abuse. Please 
contact the support or use the Webmail
```

`/etc/hosts` is correctly configured (I guess). I think it could the reason of the suspension I'm not an expert but:

```
127.0.0.1       plutone plutone.iosystems.it localhost localhost.localdomain
::1     plutone plutone.iosystems.it localhost localhost.localdomain
```

#### Old server `Received` header

Old server works fine and never got suspended/banned. Headers show the correct hostname:

```
Received: from apogeo.hpsart.it (guest2.iosystems.it
 [81.31.150.182])
```

File `/etc/hosts` is nearly identical.

**Update 1**: as suggested by @Tero Kilkanen I've changed the Reverse DNS (it was blank) from `31.193.130.251` to `plutone.iosystems.it`. It doesn't work: `Recevied` always shows `31-193-130-251.static.as29550.net` instead of the hostname.

Comment: This has nothing to do with being suspended for abuse.

Comment: @MichaelHampton in my server console it says I should set the "reverse DNS", otherwise it could be a problem when dealing with spam and filters. It may be the source of the problem? Thanks

Comment: What leads you to believe you've been banned or suspended?  With that information, someone might be able to figure out why...  the reverse DNS not being what you expect to be isn't necessarily the problem.  As long as you can lookup the name that shows up (*.static.as29550.net) forward and reverse then that is most likely not your cause at all.

Comment: Because from my old server I can send hundread of messages without being blocked. Running the same script on my new server and I get blocked after - say - 5 or 10 messages. I've updated the question.

Comment: Blocked by whom?  There's no global authority that can block your email everywhere.  There are many mechanisms that people can use to share that sort of information, but there's no 'standard'.  You should be contacting whomever is in charge of the mail server that's rejecting you.  Likely that recipient was hammered by someone using the IP you are now assigned and the block was never removed.  You can also try asking your provider for a new IP.

Comment: @yoonix blocked by the SMTP, see the updated question.

Comment: You have probably [obfuscated too much](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632). It would be helpful to have the actual IP addresses and domain names being used here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton removed the obfuscation, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your forward and reverse DNS entries are not the same. It is essential to have have the IP to DNS and DNS to IP mappings the same with E-Mail.

You should ask your hosting provider to set up the proper reverse DNS (sub.domain.com) for your server IP address.

Comment: How can you tell?  There isn't enough information here to verify that.  There may very well exist a matching forward entry for the name in the PTR record.

Comment: The `Received:` header line displayed in the question reveals this fact. And even if there exists a proper forward entry for that PTR entry, it doesn't matter in this case, because the MTA is set to use another name.

Comment: It does no such thing.  The remote SMTP server can't guess what the hostname is then look up the IP, it happens the other way around.  If the IP wasn't masked, then there would be enough information to verify that.

Comment: I've changed the reverse DNS (virtual server console allows me to do that) to myserver.mybusiness.com (I'm running 30+ domains on the new server). Is this correct or should I setup also sub.domain1.com, sub.domain2.com and so on?

Comment: You can verify the correctness by sending mail with the PHP script again and see if the Received: line contains the host name both ways.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've tried but it doesn't work (didn't changed). I guess it takes some hours to propagate the change, right?

Comment: Yes, DNS changes take time to propagate. Propagation time depends mostly on TTL.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Ok, it says it takes hours, we'll see. Thanks! Last question: sending from sub.domain.com (SMTP CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO sub.domain1.com) and having a Reverse DNS from XX-XXX-XXX-XXX to myserver.mybusiness.com is correct?

Comment: Ummm.... DNS doesn't `propagate`. The PTR record may be cached at the recipient's server but only if you've sent to that recipient within the time period of the TTL. The PTR record certainly doesn't have to `propagate` anywhere. Send an email to an email address that you haven't sent to previously. If the header looks the same as it originally did then you'll know that your configuration is still incorrect.

Comment: @joeqwerty True, sorry my inaccurate term. I meant cache expiration with propagation, although those terms are not interchangeable, although the net effect is similar.

Comment: I didn't worked. I've tested sending another email from the new server right know (9 hours after setting the PTR), and "Received" header still look like: `Received: from sub.domain.it (31-193-130-251.static.as29550.net
 [31.193.130.251])`. Any help?

Comment: Well, that server could have an old cached version of the PTR reply. Have you tried to sending to some other E-Mail account on another service?